# Getting error when create new table with laravel seeds

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Very new in Laravel here and I'm sorry if the questions is stupid. I'm trying to create new table but getting this error

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'vvas.buildings' doesn't exist

Here is my seed

```
class CreateBuildingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('buildings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('street');
            $table->string('neighborhood');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('buildings');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to CREATE table you use `Schema::create`. `Schema::table` is to MODIFY an existing table. So in your case would be

```
....
Schema::create('buildings', function (Blueprint $table) {
....
```

Here you can find more information about [Database creation and migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-tables)

***To create** a new database table, use the `create` method on the Schema facade.*

*The `table` method on the Schema facade may be used to **update existing** tables.*